# Запятая между "а" и "если"

Tags: пунктуация, запятые, союзы, спп, присоединительный-союз

Когда на стыке союзов "а" и "если" нужна запятая?
Например, в этом предложении нужна запятая?

***А(,) если это задача, требующая решения, что будет в итоге?***

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Запятая не нужна:
***А если** это задача, требующая решения, что будет в итоге?*

> **2)** после присоединительного союза ***а*** запятая не ставится: ***А когда** взошло солнце, перед нами открылся вид на снеговую вершину; **А если** верить сообщениям синоптиков, завтра должно наступить потепление*.

[**Запятая на стыке двух союзов**](http://old-rozental.ru/punctuatio.php?sid=140) (справочник Розенталя)

Comment: Все как есть, плюсую.